# Disable navigation on different tabs, multiple instances of browser

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session, session-variables

**Assumption:**
I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC 4 application, where I use a form authentication to authenticate my users.

When one of users is logged in my web application, he can navigate anywhere and perform all operations that my web application let him do.

Considering that my web application interacts with other third party system, each user action could involve in a potential dangerous situation.

Example of Situation: the user opens two tabs in IE, goes in the same page in which he can perform an Update operation (which is immediatly sended to the third party system), and perform an Edit action in two different moments.
Indipendently of the third party system's behavior, in case of similar situations, my web application shouldn't permit the user to perform this actions.
**Goal**
What I want to do is a UI control that redirects the user when he tries to navigate the same page for the second time (before he leave the first page).

I already thought about tracing each user's access to each page.
To do this, I think to make an AJAX call to my Controller (in MVC) on `document.ready` event and on `window.onbeforeunload` event.
At each event, my Controller should read and write user's data in a database table.

I noticed that once an user is logged through form authentication, he shares **session** information over different tabs and browser instances (as long as at least one is open).

**Are there any differences, in terms of information, that I can intercept, when a user navigates over different tabs or browser instances ?**

Is it possible to do what I want, without using frameworks like SignalR (*in which I'm not an expert*) ?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going about this the wrong way.  Instead of trying to do this on the client side, you need to be doing something inside the update to detect and prevent a duplicate operation.

How you would go about this really depends on how you've structured the internals of your application.

For example, you could track the update operations that are performed by a user, and ensure that only a single update operation can be performed.

If the user has already performed the update, your POST action can perform the redirect that you mention doing via Ajax.

Whilst SignalR could be used in a way to attempt to prevent the double update, it would be trivial for a user to bypass this mechanism.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what I want to do. I want that the User can't arrive to the final page, this prevent all CRUD scenarios. Also, I don't have to put a limit over the number of crud operations. About this point, I don't have no idea, about how to handle user's access to the method.

Comment: What I am saying is that trying to prevent the user from doing something **on the client side only** is quite difficult, if not impossible.  An end user would be able to workaround any client side barriers that you put up.  The most reliable way is to maintain state about the user and/or the object(s) that they are updating on the server side, where you can **trust** that the state hasn't been manipulated.

Comment: Can you suggest me any framework, or architectyral pattern to use (except SignalR, I can't use it due to server's limits) ? All usefull examples are welcome.

Comment: You'll have to post more details on your architecture, data models, and details about your application.

Comment: Off the top of my head, you can use some type of concurrency check (e.g. have each record in the database store a timestamp that is updated each time the record is updated.  When you perform an updated, you pass the timestamp in and only update if it matches - otherwise the record has been changed already.

Comment: I work on different multi-layer solutions. This behavior will be welcome over all. Generally ASP.NET MVC application that consume WCF web services. I'm used to use 3 layers for web services: WCF layer, Business logic layer and Data Access layer. For Data Access I'm used to use Entity framework database first, code first, and even Unit of Work pattern over code first.